# java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up

Tags: spring-boot, dockerfile

I tried creating and running a docker container for spring boot application using mysql , but when I try to run the container for spring application it fails with the following error- it is not able to connect to mysql server.
[application.properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXRW7.png)
[dockerFile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3EmQ3.png)

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBRR6.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gs8Fc.png)

I was trying to create and run a docker container for the springboot mysql application

Answer (score 0):

1. You are using a environment variable **MYSQL_HOST** in your spring datasource url. Make sure you are passing a value to that env variable in your Dockerfile or docker-compose.yml (if you are using one).
2. I didn't understand why you have enclosed **localhost** in the environment variable. My suggestion would be to remove it and pass the host name in Dockerfile or docker-compose.yml.
3. You can make use of spring profiles, to change the data source url accordingly based on the environment you run. You application.properties file would look something like.... (I prefer using yml file, so provided a example of the same)
   [image]

Comment: I replaced local host with the sql container but it is still not working, the problem is with "spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create" statement in application.properties, it is not working, if I remove that statement the container is running but it is not creating the tables

Comment: Can you share your docker-compose file ?